# Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: read ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I am building a script in Nodejs to scrape 7000 urls from a certain website.

The script runs in the beginning as it should do, but after a certain time it looks like it is losing speed and power and starts to log errors till it stops (see errors below).

Is there something I can do with the timeout settings of Node / express or set a timeout in my script?

**Errors:**

```
Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at new RequestError (/Users/robbertvermeulen/Workspace/Node/scrape/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/Users/robbertvermeulen/Workspace/Node/scrape/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/Users/robbertvermeulen/Workspace/Node/scrape/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/Users/robbertvermeulen/Workspace/Node/scrape/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/Users/robbertvermeulen/Workspace/Node/scrape/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

**My script:**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request-promise');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var async   = require('async');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {

   // Base url
   const baseURL = 'https://www.example.com';

   // Final data
   var json = [];   

   var archiveURLs = []; // Holds a list of archive urls

   // Loop trough archive urls
   async.forEach(archiveURLs, function(url, mainCallback) {

      async.waterfall([

         // Find post urls on archive urls
         function(firstCallback) {

            request(url, function(error, response, html) {

               if (! error && 200 == response.statusCode) {
                  var paths = [];
                  $ = cheerio.load(html);
                  $('h2 a').each(function(index, element) {
                     var path = $(element).attr('href');
                     paths.push(path);
                  });
                  firstCallback(null, paths);
               }
            });

         },

         // Fetch data from post urls
         function(paths, secondCallback) {

            var fetchData = [];

            async.forEach(paths, function(path, loopCallback) {

               var item = {title: '', url: ''};
               var url = baseURL + path;

               console.log('Fetching', url);

               request(url, function(error, response, html) {
                  if (! error) {
                     $ = cheerio.load(html);
                     item.title = $('h1').text().trim();
                     item.url = url;
                     fetchData.push(item);
                     loopCallback();
                  }
               });

            }, function(err) {

               // Store fetched data in array
               for (i = 0; i < fetchData.length; i ++) {
                  json.push(fetchData[i]);
               }
               secondCallback(null, 1);
            });
         }

      ],
      function(err, result) {
         mainCallback();
      });

   }, function(err) {

      // Scrape finished

   });

   // Writes message to browser
   res.send('Check your console!')

})

app.listen('8081');
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

**UPDATE:**

I handle my errors now like this:

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
   if (! error) {
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
         // Code
         loopCallback();
      }
   } else {
      return res.end(error.message);
   }
}).on('error', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
}).end();
```

Comment: A quick look at your code, seems you are not handling the error case in your request callback `if (! error && 200 == response.statusCode)` is there but what if there is error, waterfall next task will never be called?

Comment: @RistoNovik I recently updated my code. Check de update in my question. I have found this here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/636 It looks like the errors are gone now, but I still am not able the run all the urls..

Comment: Don't use the `request-promise` module when your code is working with callbacks. Or rather: don't use the `async` module when you want to work with promises!

Comment: @Bergi I indeed removed the request promise module already. Do you think async.queue can do the job?

Comment: Could you refactor the flow with promises, it's really hard to understand which callback currently is not handled properly? Yes you did add the `.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
}).end();` but when error occours you are only logging, shouldn't it call the `firstCallback(null, []);`?